# combining plugin 'kotlin-parcelize' with plugin 'kotlin-android-extensions'

Tags: java, android, kotlin

I understand that 'kotlin-android-extensions' are becoming deprecated and they should be replaced in the future, but I have a problem.
I am working on a big legacy android project written in mixed java and kotlin. Kotlin part uses heavily 'kotlin-android-extensions' and to replace them all with f.e. findVievById or view binding is a hell of a job.

My task is to implement JUMIO SDK into the app which has one mandatory requirement. It must use 'kotlin-parcelize' plugin.
The problem is that kotlin parcelize and kotlin-android-extensions can't be mixed together.

the error I get is:

:app: 'kotlin-parcelize' can't be applied together with 'kotlin-android-extensions'

Does anyone have idea how to fix this? Thanks

Comment: It looks like ``parcelize`` is part of ``kotlin-android-extensions``, and the plugin has been created as a separate component now the extensions have been deprecated. Does your SDK definitely require the actual plugin? Maybe you can get it to work with the ``parcelize`` stuff that comes with the extensions - you might need to use older versions of stuff that's all compatible with the dependencies in your codebase though. (Refactoring to use ``findViewById`` might not be so bad though - you just need to recreate the automagic variable for each view in the top level of each activity etc)

Comment: Yes ,new version of sdk requires stand-alone parcelize plugin. But I found work around to stay on older version of SDK that doesn't require it but still keep my sdk working since I manually added new Iproov provider in code.
Anyways thanks for your time and answer!